# What do the different types of approach abbreviations used on the A320 MCDU exactly mean?

Tags: airbus-a320, approach, fms

On the MCDU I have noticed after setting up the approach there are a number of different codes which appear next to the runway designator these are namely as below:

CI
CF
FI
CD
FD

Can someone kindly explain what these codes mean.

Comment: _Hopes OP is setting up approaches in a flight sim, not the real thing..._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CI = course to intercept

CF = course to fix

FI = fix to intercept

CD = course to DME

FD = fix to DME

These are AIRINC 424 leg types. You can find more information on them [here](https://www.ifr-magazine.com/system/arinc-424-leg-types/)